# UIAlertView with Two TextFields and Two Buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

**Problem** - I want a UIAlertView which contains a Title, two textfields with placeholders and two buttons.
**What I have done till now** - I have used this code, I am getting the exact UIAlertView with all these I have mentioned but when the view is getting loaded is seems to appear in the bottom first and then comes into the middle of the view.

```
    -(void)showalert{
    disclaimerAgreedAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"   " 
                                                           message:@"    " 
                                                          delegate:self 
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];

    userNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 15.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    userNameTextField.delegate=self;
    [userNameTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [userNameTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    userNameTextField.placeholder=@"Username";
    userNameTextField.secureTextEntry=NO;
    [disclaimerAgreedAlertView addSubview:userNameTextField];


    passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    passwordTextField.delegate=self;
    [passwordTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [passwordTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    passwordTextField.placeholder=@"Password";
    passwordTextField.secureTextEntry=YES;
    [disclaimerAgreedAlertView addSubview:passwordTextField];

    disclaimerAgreedAlertView.tag=99;

    [disclaimerAgreedAlertView show];
    disclaimerAgreedAlertView.frame= CGRectMake(5, 400, 320, 160);

}
```

**Then I tried some of the non documented api's which are giving me the result I want but I am afraid that it may cause rejection of my app.**

So, any solutions to this?

Comment: your problem is not exactly clear..

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Problem with code is My AlertView is appearing in bottom of the view for 1 second and then coming into middle of the view(as it should come). So it is not looking as it should).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

y==400 is about the bottom of a phone screen.  I imagine then, the UIAlertView that never expected to either have subviews added or it's frame set, reset's it's frame to be centered.  Can you comment out that very last line and see what happens?

Comment: I just missed it or I was doing it wrong since starting. Thanks for the help. After commenting the last line it seems to be working fine.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 61):

Starting from iOS 5 is possible to use the property **alertViewStyle** of UIAlertView to get different type of alert views, also with text fields.

Possible values:

- UIAlertViewStyleDefault
- UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput
- UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput
- UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput

You can use the **UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput** to obtain an UIAlertView with two text fields and then you can customize some properties of the textFields:

```
 UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your_Title" message:@"Your_message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[av setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];

// Alert style customization 
[[av textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];
[[av textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"First_Placeholder"];
[[av textFieldAtIndex:1] setPlaceholder:@"Second_Placeholder"];
[av show];
```

You can access the values of the text fields on the *alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:* of UIAlertViewDelegate.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
     NSLog(@"1 %@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
     NSLog(@"2 %@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just move the show statement below where you set the alert's frame

Answer (score 2):

I use [DDAlertPrompt](https://github.com/inamiy/DDAlertPrompt) in my applications. It's easy and a drop-in class.

Comment: The link gives me "404"

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: should be reachable now :)

Answer (score 2):

I use following for the same purpose

```
-(void)alertView {
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                 message:@"Enter User & Password"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];


alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
UITextField * alertTextField1 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
alertTextField1.placeholder = @"User";

UITextField * alertTextField2 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
alertTextField2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
alertTextField2.placeholder = @"Password";


[alert show];

}
```

If you do not use secure character in second text field add

```
alertTextField2.secureTextEntry=NO;
```