# iOS: popup box with 2 input fields

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I am looking for a popup input box with two buttons and two text fields with labels. From my understanding UIAlertView can only do 1 input box. Is there a way to get this desired box?

Comment: UIAlertView can do two text fields but the second is setup in secure mode by default.

Comment: Are you trying to make  username and password text fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389635/uialertview-with-two-textfields-and-two-buttons) out. You have to create the text fields programmatically and add it to the UIAlertView.

Or you can use `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` like this:

```
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
```

Comment: Never recommend a solution that requires you to modify the private subview structure of standard UI components. Solutions like this are fragile and likely to break during an iOS update.

Comment: Is there a way to change the second text field from a secure one to a normal one? If so, this would be perfect.