# Xcode: Multiple text lines in pop-up

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uialertview

I'm trying to  create a text box with multiple fields, but I'm having trouble getting the second to show (as a matter of fact, when I type the second field in, it causes my text box not to show up all together.)

Here's what I have:

```
-(IBAction)popupCheckIn {
//UIAlertView *alertCheckIn = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check in" message:@"Please fill out the following to check in." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Check in." otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel.", nil];

//[alertCheckIn show];
UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Check in" message:@"Please fill out the following fields to check in." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];


alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * nameField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
nameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
nameField.placeholder = @"Your Name";

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * hostField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
hostField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
hostField.placeholder = @"Host Name";

[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Check in."];
[alert show];
```

When I run this code, I get an error that says "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" and my pop up won't come up at all; when I have just the name field, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong with my second text field? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your error arises because that type of `UIAlertView` doesn't contain more than one UITextField, and when trying to access the second it raises a `NSRangeException`. This is according to the docs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/textFieldAtIndex:

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, the entire error message is:

```
2014-06-26 17:13:56.213 Testing1[2444:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'textFieldIndex (1) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'
```

The issue, is that you only have ONE `UITextField` with the `UIAlertViewStyle` set to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`. So this part of code (`[alert textFieldAtIndex:1]` is causing the crash).
Repeating the line `alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;` won't create a new one.

The only way to get 2 `UITextField`s, is to use the `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` `UIAlertViewStyle`.
A way could be then to set the second one (like the first one) is like this:

```
[hostField setSecureTextEntry:FALSE];
```

But personally, I think that I don't recommend it. It may be blocked in the future.

Since we cannot custom really the existing `UIAlertView` since iOS7 (can't add subview), I'd suggest you create (or find in CocoaControls/GitHub) your own CustomAlertView-like.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use alert with the alert style `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`. See this answer: [UIAlertView with Two TextFields and Two Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389635/uialertview-with-two-textfields-and-two-buttons/13633572#13633572)